# Not able to detect talk events in confBridge 10

Tags: asterisk

I am using confBridge in my asterisk for conferencing.
I want to detect who is talking and who is not talking inside a conference.
For this there is an option in confBridge "talk_detection_events=yes" this sends the talk events to AMI, but it only sends the talk events when the user joins a conference and after that I am not able to see any events in AMI.
I want that whenever a user starts talking or stops talking there should be an event triggered in AMI.

Or, is there any command by which I can detect if a user is talking or not in confbridge?

Also, I want to detect keypress (dtmf) events in confbridge. There is an option "dtmf_passthrough=yes" which pass the dtmf events to the AMI, but I did not see any events when a user presses any key in a conference.

Please help me in setting up these.

Regards
Anil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Talk Detection:**

While setting talk_detection_events=yes will enable sending AMI events out denoting when a user begins/ends talking, that may not be sufficient to configure your ConfBridge depending on several other factors.

Whether or not a user is determined to be 'talking' depends on combinations of the dsp_talking_threshold and dsp_silence_threshold settings.  If you are not receiving the talk detection events that you expect, then you may need to tweak these settings to match the audio properties that ConfBridge is receiving from its participants.

Alternatively, you should ensure that your AMI account has sufficient class permissions to receive the Talk Detection events.  The event has the EVENT_FLAG_CALL class permission, and you should be listening for the event ConfbridgeTalking.

**DTMF**

dtmf_passthrough has nothing to do with the actual raising of the DTMF AMI event, which is done by the channel read/write routines.  dtmf_passthrough allows the DTMF key presses to be sent to the other channels in the bridge - typically, the ConfBridge application absorbs the DTMF key presses.

With this enabled, you should see DTMF events - at a minimum - on the Bridging channel.  If you aren't seeing events of any kind, you most likely don't have the appropriate class permissions set on the AMI account.

All of that being said, I have to wonder why you're looking for the DTMF key presses.  In general, actions on channels in ConfBridge should take place using the menu system implemented in ConfBridge, or using the AMI/CLI commands.  You'd be hard pressed to accurately intercept and handle a channel's DTMF while it was still in the conference bridge - the channel, at that point, is in owned by the bridge layer, and anything you choose to do to that channel is almost certainly unsafe.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your response. It worked perfectly. Now I am facing another challenge. I have 20 channels in a conference so at one time 2 channels are unmuted and other 18 are muted, after after few minutes of conference I want to unmute a channel who is trying to speak, now the challenge is the person who is trying to speak is muted and I can't detect his talk events either so that I can unmute him. So is there anyway such that I can detect the talk events of a muted channel/person in confbridge.

Comment: No, that isn't currently possible.  The TalkDetect events will fire for those channels whose audio frames are being mixed by the bridging layer - if a channel is muted, its audio frames never get to that point.

To some extent, you could run into problems with that feature anyway - if someone is muted and someone else starts talking and you unmute them, why have them muted?  You'd be bound to lose some of their audio in the process, which means they'd have to repeat what they said.  A better process may be to give them a mechanism via a DTMF menu to notify the speaker that they'd like to talk.

Comment: Then, you could have the speaker acknowledge them by having them unmute them.  If you wanted that controlled via AMI and not by the speaker, you could have the DTMF menu bounce out to the dialplan and raise a UserEvent.  You could then programmatically unmute the participant.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try that way. I have one more problem, Is there any command in confbrdige by which I can kick all the channels in a conference? I can see command by which I can kick only one channel at a time but what if I want to kick all the channels  from a conference room in one go? Your suggestions are really helpful please help me in this also.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have detected talk events on sending channel sucessfully but i need to detect it on both channels means sending and receiving, e.g channelstarttalking, stoptalking etc.. will you please guide me how can i be able to receive the events from both channel?